# Decode Base64 String in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Base64 encoded file and I am trying the following to decode it:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data))
```

However it generates the following error:

```
Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding 
characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

Although it is Base64, completely. Any ideas?

*Please note that it is Base64, but not encoded by PowerShell.

Comment: Can you check that the file does not have a UTF [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start?

Comment: It does not have the mentioned

Comment: *Although it is Base64, completely* - I'm afraid I believe PowerShell saying it isn't more than I believe you saying it is. How are you creating $data - does it have line ending `\n` characters in it maybe?

Comment: If you are initializing $data with a literal string for e.g. "TestString" then it should not be a problem but if you are getting its value by executing another poweshell command for e.g. $data = <SomePowerShellCommand> then you will have to be cautious. Try seeing the value of $data variable using Write-Verbose on powershell before u actually use it later in code. I was doing something similar: $data = Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName
Here the Get-AzureStorageKey command returns an array of primary and secondary key while I was thinking it would return me a string.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to decode a Base64 string to text this will do:

```
$EncodedText = 'SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh'
$DecodedText = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EncodedText))
$DecodedText
```

If you need to decode a Base64 string to a binary file this will do:

```
$base64string = ''
$FileName = "file.png"
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FileName, [Convert]::FromBase64String($base64string))
```

Comment: Works like a charm for base64 encoded ZIP files, thank you. Took some time to find this WriteAllBytes method here. Thumbs up man!

Answer (score 0):

Some applications require the Base64 string to end with one or two equal signs as the padding character. For a quick test you can add one or two "=" characters at the end of your variable $data like this:

`[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data+"="))`

and try decoding again.

See [Decoding Base64 with padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Decoding_Base64_with_padding)